# filter array so that objects with same property only appear once in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following array:

```
[
  {name: "Joske", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Mieke", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Jan", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Test", code: "IsxJK"},
  {name: "Koen", code: "IsxJK"},
]
```

And I need a function which gives me an array of objects where there is only once occurrence of the code property:

```
[
  {name: "Joske", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Test", code: "IsxJK"},
]
```

I have thought about it and I think I'm making it harder than it needs to be. Does someone has a simple function to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your array based on `code` using `array#reduce` in an object accumulator and extract all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = [{ name: "Joske", code: "IEDDK" }, { name: "Mieke", code: "IEDDK" }, { name: "Jan", code: "IEDDK" }, { name: "Test", code: "IsxJK" }, { name: "Koen", code: "IsxJK" }, ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
      r[o.code] = r[o.code] || o;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a "last wins", this can be done nicely with

```js
[...new Map(data.map(d => [d.code, d])).values()]
```

with `O(n)` complexity (unlike some other approaches that re-iterate the array for every member, looking for matches thereby exhibiting quadratic complexity).

For a "first wins", just reverse your data:

```js
[...new Map([...data].reverse().map(d => [d.code, d])).values()]
```

This can be folded into a typesafe generic function:

```js
const distinctBy = <T, K>(data: T[], keySelector: (v: T) => K): T[] => 
    [...new Map(data.map(d => [keySelector(d), d])).values()]
```

and used

```js
distinctBy(data, d => d.code)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvGMBAWwFMAuGAIgCkQIBrUqgGhlDguoEkBRAEX4BpKjAC+LHPkIkuVALIBLUk1bsQnSlT6CR4ybgJEyWmgjBqOcncNESpR2VoAqpaJY3WIADxp77hjIm1EIgpBZsVlrcPn52kgC6WFigkLAANgjQAOqKkGiYAHTFYKQA7jDyCAAOABSIyIXENfVoAHyYcIVWbHAJAJT9hQBuCOkArm61-UmpECDppIXpIADmtZk5eRD9KeDQMABmigBOW-noGMWFpRVVdVfFDQgJhSekw6RnpNNNLXDtTrdTy9AZDUYTKYzPaQBZLFbrY5nKC5SC7GEHOCKaB5YBQABCAE8CgAeZxsIRtepIBCUZwYBJsJiEgDKpEWeJAJ0otWGdP6gKE-TpDMBjxu5Uq-xpfzqANQHQwzLZHKgXPq-VBgxGY0mEGmSQxcOWa3q2KguIJhOpyDYw0Bw2BnEGQA)

Answer (score 0):

You coud  use a `forEach` with `find` method, this way:

```js
let data = [ { name: "Joske", code: "IEDDK" }, { name: "Mieke", code: "IEDDK" },{ name: "Jan", code: "IEDDK" }, { name: "Test", code: "IsxJK" }, { name: "Koen", code: "IsxJK" }];

const removeSimilar = (array) => {
  let result = [];
  array.forEach((item) => {
    if (!result.find((i) => i.code === item.code)) result.push(item);
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(removeSimilar(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `filter` and `findIndex` is also an option:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "Joske", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Mieke", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Jan", code: "IEDDK"},
  {name: "Test", code: "IsxJK"},
  {name: "Koen", code: "IsxJK"},
];

const isTheSameAs = ({ code }) => item => item.code === code;

const filteredArr = arr
    .filter((item, indexInOriginalArray, array) => array.findIndex(isTheSameAs(item)) === indexInOriginalArray);

console.log(filteredArr);
```